# subprocess.run with embedded null byte in argument

Tags: python

I am analyzing a program with the symbolic executor [KLEE](https://klee.github.io/) and writing a Python helper script for the output. KLEE generates test values for the input values which I now want to use with `subprocess.run` to execute in an Address Sanitizer enabled binary.

Unfortunately, I receive a

> ValueError: embedded null byte

when executing the following code:

```py
def run_with_arguments(directory: str, executable: str):
    path = Path(directory)
    for test_path in path.glob("*.ktest"):
        print(f"Checking ktest file {test_path.absolute()}")
        ktest = KTest.fromfile(test_path.absolute())
        args = [arg[1] for arg in ktest.objects if arg[0].startswith("arg")]
        stdin = next((arg[1] for arg in ktest.objects if arg[0] == "stdin"), None)
        command = [executable.encode("utf-8")]
        command.extend(args)
        print(f"Executing command {command}, stdin={stdin}...")
        subprocess.run(command, input=stdin, check=True)
```

with this test data:

```
Checking ktest file /home/klee/project/klee-out-31/test000014.ktest
Executing command [b'myapp.asan', b'--\x00\xff\xff\xff'], stdin=b'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'...
```

Is there any way to pass a byte object with embedded null bytes? On the shell, I could execute

```
./myapp.asan $(cat klee-out-31/test000014.ktest.arg00)
```

but then I would have to save all the embedded arguments from the ktest files to external files, which I want to avoid.

Comment: You can't pass NUL bytes on a program's argument list at all, ever: The UNIX syscall interface uses C strings. C strings are terminated by NULs. Thus, they cannot possibly contain NULs within their contents.

Comment: ...when you run `./myapp.asan $(cat klee-out-31/test000014.ktest.arg00)`, assuming that file really does contain NUL literals, it either just deletes the NULs and runs the command without them, or ends the command line at the first one, depending on exactly which shell version you have. In new enough versions of bash, it'll delete the NULs _and write a warning to stderr telling you it did so_.

Comment: ...not being able to pass NULs around in C strings is part of why generating shellcode is tricky (though these days there are lots of tools that automate the process, to be sure).

Comment: BTW, what _would_ be interesting is to run `set -x; ./myapp.asan $(cat klee-out-31/test000014.ktest.arg00)` -- it'll emit the actual argument list it's using in an unambiguous form, so we can see what it actually is. (It'll be quoted in a form that's basically output from bash's version of the Python `repr()` builtin, but getting from that bash literal to a Python literal is easy enough).

Comment: BTW, have you considered `command = [executable.encode("utf-8").split(b'\x00')]`? That'll probably be exactly what you want, since -- remember -- NULs as used as *terminators* for C strings, so end a C string on each NUL, and you get a byte sequence equivalent to your original code. (I'm not sure UTF-8 is appropriate -- you should probably be getting the data into your code as a bytestring in the first place rather than a multi-byte character string -- but that's a whole different discussion).

Comment: ...I _suspect_ that what you had in your legacy code was the shell terminating each argument on a NUL, but whether that's the behavior you actually get is version-dependent and not guaranteed! It's more reliable to use `xargs -0 ./myapp.asan < klee-out-31/test000014.ktest.arg00`, if what you want is arguments split on NULs onto an argv; that avoids other shell behaviors you'd get from unquoted expansion, like globbing and word-splitting on other non-NUL characters (spaces and such).

Comment: Thanks! After posting the question, it also occured to me. I just wonder why KLEE creates this input data as arguments in the first place, if it uses the POSIX interface... I guess I'll go dig in the KLEE source code.

Comment: NUL-delimiting a list of C strings is an unambiguous way to represent each of those items, without needing to do any kind of encoding or escaping (and thus, without the other end needing to undo those steps). On the other hand, if they aren't documenting the format as being a list of separate NUL-separated arguments, that does indeed seem unfortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULs are used to terminate C strings. From this simple observation, two consequences:

- You cannot possibly pass a NUL inside a single C string (hence the warning from the Python interpreter passing up to you a limitation from the underlying OS).
- If you want to reproduce a given sequence of bytes in an *array of C strings*, end each string inside that array at the position where a NUL should be.

Thus:

```
command = [executable.encode("utf-8").split(b'\x00')]
```

<sub>Note that the `.encode("utf-8")` is a bit of a code smell; if you were doing it right, your `executable` would be a bytestring, not a string of multi-byte characters, in the first place; so it wouldn't need to be encoded at all.</sub>